# How to add authentication to socket for sending email in c++

Tags: c++, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm new to c++, and want to send mail using c++ sockets.where do i need to add host username and password.

This is for linux, in the past i have tried to send the mail using socket that works fine for smtp mail server that does'nt require authenticaion. But for mail server having authentication it retrieves access denied.

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/socket.h>
        #include <netinet/in.h>
        #include <netdb.h>
        #include <stdio.h>



        #include <sstream>
        #include <unistd.h> 

        #include <iomanip>
        #include <cstring>

        #include <stdlib.h> 

        #include <string.h> 


        using namespace std;
        #define HELO "HELO 192.168.1.1\r\n"
        #define DATA "DATA\r\n"
        #define QUIT "QUIT\r\n"

        //#define h_addr h_addr_list[0]
        //FILE *fin;
        int sock;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct hostent *hp, *gethostbyname();
        char buf[BUFSIZ+1];
        int len;
        char *host_id="mail.exampple.de";
        char *from_id="test@example.de";
        char *to_id="test@eee.com";
        char *sub="testmail\r\n";
        char wkstr[100]="hello how r u\r\n";

        /*=====Send a string to the socket=====*/

        void send_socket(char *s)
        {
        write(sock,s,strlen(s));
        write(1,s,strlen(s));
        //printf("Client:%s\n",s);
        }

        //=====Read a string from the socket=====*/

        void read_socket()
        {
        len = read(sock,buf,BUFSIZ);
        write(1,buf,len);
        //printf("Server:%s\n",buf);
        }

        /*=====MAIN=====*/
        int main(int argc, char* argv[])
        {

        /*=====Create Socket=====*/
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock==-1)
        {  
            perror("opening stream socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            cout << "socket created\n";

        /*=====Verify host=====*/
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hp = gethostbyname(host_id);
        if (hp==(struct hostent *) 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unknown host\n", host_id);
            exit(2);
        }

        /*=====Connect to port 25 on remote host=====*/
        memcpy((char *) &server.sin_addr, (char *) hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
        server.sin_port=htons(25); /* SMTP PORT */
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof server)==-1)
        {
            perror("connecting stream socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            cout << "Connected\n";
        /*=====Write some data then read some =====*/
        read_socket(); /* SMTP Server logon string */
        send_socket(HELO); /* introduce ourselves */
        read_socket(); /*Read reply */
        send_socket("MAIL FROM: "); 
        send_socket(from_id);
        send_socket("\r\n");
        read_socket(); /* Sender OK */
        send_socket("VRFY ");
        send_socket(from_id);
        send_socket("\r\n");
        read_socket(); // Sender OK */
        send_socket("RCPT TO: "); /*Mail to*/
        send_socket(to_id);
        send_socket("\r\n");
        read_socket(); // Recipient OK*/
        send_socket(DATA);// body to follow*/
        send_socket("Subject: ");
        send_socket(sub);
        read_socket(); // Recipient OK*/
        send_socket(wkstr);
        send_socket(".\r\n");
        read_socket(); 
        send_socket(QUIT); /* quit */
        read_socket(); // log off */

        //=====Close socket and finish=====*/
        close(sock);
        exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: There are lots of examples.  Here is one: https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet  or maybe this http://woshub.com/sending-email-via-telnet-using-smtp-authentication/

Comment: This is not c++ related at all, at least unless you use some existing library for smtp.
See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321 for smtp protocol specification and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954 for authentication. You might be better off using a library, because there are a lot of different authentication methods.

Comment: @MofX will you plz explain me how it will be usefull for that above code. I want to implement the authentication with socket

Comment: The socket is just a means to communicate with the smtp server. You told us, you are able to send mails using servers without authentication, so the communication is working. What is missing now is the authentication. For some lighter to read description of smtp auth see: https://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm